# Terminal Server Licensing: This Licensing ID will expire within 90 days

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I logged into my Microsoft portal to check out if I can migrate my Terminal Services licenses from a 2003 to 2008 server and I got red message saying: "This Licensing ID will expire within 90 days".

What exactly does that error message mean in practical terms? Will I have to purchase new licenses or is it just Software Assurance expiration?

Comment: no, that question covers licencing issues, not 'all questions that can possibly be vaguely related to licencing'.  And certainly not technical questions asking what a specific error or warning means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the ID you use to log into the VLSC is going to expire, for some reason - could be that the agreement is up for renewal or someone removed you as administrator.   As with most licensing questions its best to contact the vendor (in this case microsoft) to find out what's happening.